# Oracle TO_DATE with only time input will add date component based on what logic?

Tags: oracle, date

Running this code in Oracle 11/12:

```
select to_date('101200', 'hh24miss') from dual
```

will return a DATE component that Oracle automatically adds based on what logic?

Eg:

```
select to_char(to_date('101200', 'hh24miss'), 'yyyymmdd') from dual
```

returns

```
20160701
```

We see the added date component is always set to the first day of the current month. Where does this logic come from?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A value of `date` data type  always has date and time components. if you specify only time portion of the datetime value as you did, the date portion defaults to the first day of the current month.

Comment: That is probably just how the default behavior for the function is implemented.  If you are asking if you can change that behavior, I don't think so.

Comment: The question seems clear to me, but like many other "why did Oracle do it this way" type questions, there's unlikely to be a satisfactory answer. They had to pick a default value so they did. I'd have picked one that doesn't change every month, but then I'm not Oracle. At least we have `INTERVAL` since 9i.

Comment: Are you asking WHY Oracle made that choice? Or are you asking if this behavior that you noticed is in fact documented? (It is.) If you are asking WHY, I doubt it's the right type of question for SO.

Comment: Since I couldn't find it documented anywhere and also Google searches don't really provide a good answer, I thought of asking here. It seems really weird for Oracle to default to the first day of the current month.

So yes, if it's documented, can you please provide a link to it? Thanks again

Comment: [Here you go](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062). 7th paragraph. There is also undocumented `TIME` literal and `TIME` data type (needs to be enabled) if you need to use and store just time, without date part. But again it's undocumented and unsupported feature.

Comment: Cheers Nicholas, super thank you very much. Would you like to add it as actual answer to my question? I will accept it. Thank again, have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A value of date data type always has date and time components. if you specify only time portion of the datetime value as you did, the date portion defaults to the first day of the current month.

[Here is one of the places (7th paragraph)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) in the Oracle documentation where this behavior is documented.

There is also undocumented `TIME` literal and `TIME` data type (needs to be enabled via `10407` (datetime TIME datatype creation) event) if you need to use and store just time, without date part.

Here is a small demonstration of using `time` literal and `time` data type. But again it's undocumented and unsupported feature.

```
SQL> select time '11:32:00' as res
  2    from dual;

res 
------------------------  
11.32.00.000000000 AM
```

You can use time literal without enabling `10407` event, but in order to be able to define a column of `time` data type the `10407` event needs to be enabled:

```
SQL> create table time_table(time_col time);
create table time_table(time_col time)
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype   

-- enable 10407 event 
SQL> alter session set events '10407 trace name context forever, level 1';

Session altered.
```

Now we can create a table with a column of `time` data type:

```
SQL> create table time_table(time_col time);

Table created.


SQL> insert into time_table(time_col)
  2    values(time '11:34:00');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from time_table;

TIME_COL 
--------------- 
11.34.00 AM

SQL> alter session set events '10407 trace name context off';

Session altered.
```

Comment: While fascinating (I learned something new today, yay!), the undocumented and unsupported TIME literal feature is not really relevant to answering this question, which was specifically about TO_DATE.

Comment: I'll still accept it. The question was answered and extra interesting info was added, so even better ;)