# Default Day using to_Date with time only

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to get a date in oracle with today's date plus a provided time (hours and minutes)

The query was:

```
select TO_DATE ('02:03', 'hh24:mi') from dual
```

I was surprised by the result:

```
01/08/2017 02:03:00
```

It seems that the day is defaulted to the 1st of the month (I tried this on 3rd of the month) but the month and year are preserved.

Is that something expected or documented anywhere?

Comment: That is the default behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find the answer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ)

> If you specify a date value without a date, then the default date is
>   the first day of the current month.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Turns out the question was already asked https://stackoverflow.com/q/38637524/3997278